# when using DelayedJobs, info about worker thread doesn't print in console until foreman is killed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, delayed-job

I've noticed this problem for the past couple weeks when developing using the DelayedJobs gem.

I start a Rails server in a terminal and I get info back from both the web and work threads:

```
foreman start
22:10:31 web.1    | started with pid 10128
22:10:31 worker.1 | started with pid 10129
```

However, after this point only the web thread prints information to the console. It's not until I kill foreman that I get the complete dump of everything having to do with the worker thread during the entire server execution all at once on the console.

Any way to get the worker thread information printed out to the console in real time during development?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to status on [this issue](https://github.com/ddollar/foreman/issues/180), the newest version of foreman should be flushing logs on its own.